# How to have the generate javascript files get stored into project directory?

Tags: gatsby

When I view source of my static website page, I can see the javascript `commons.js` used. But I can't find this file into the project directories.

It seems that I can only see the compiled`commons.js` file when I build the project for production.

Is there an option to generated the `commons.js` file while development? I need to have it served by another framework like RubyOnRails or Django in development to build views, is this possible? how?

Comment: JavaScript is interpreted at runtime but not compiled.. I dont know what you are talking about

Comment: I mean the javascript file that is generated from the reactJS project

Comment: I would change "complied" to "bundled and minified" to be clear.

Comment: There are quite a few Node.js based asset pipelines such as webpack and gulp which are standalone. You can even use Sprockets (the assets pipeline used by Rails) on its own.